# Flask: Как отобразить на сайте надпись о работе подпроцесса Python?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

У меня есть 4 паука Scrapy, которых я запускаю через Flask. После нажатия на кнопку Scrape запускается подпроцесс (паук). Также отображается сообщение о том, что подпроцесс работает. Но если перезагрузить страницу, то надпись исчезнет. Как это исправить?

кнопка:

```
<button id="scrape" class="btn btn-success mr-2">Scrape</button>

$('#scrape').on('click', () => {
    $('#status').text('Scraper is working...')
    $.post('/wellness', {'specialty': specialty, 'state': state, 'city': city, 'email': email}, (res) => {
      $('#status').text('') 
      $(location).attr('href', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/wellness')
    });
  });
```

flask:

```
@app.route('/<page_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def page(page_id):
    file_py = f"{page_id}.py"

    if request.method == 'POST':
        process = subprocess.Popen('python spiders/' + file_py, shell = True)
        process.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

Более простой способ это поставить scrapyd. И обращаться к нему по API:
Например запустить паука:

```
$ curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=somespider
```

Посмотреть джобы:

```
$ curl http://localhost:6800/listjobs.json?project=myproject
```

(https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/491778)

Comment: @SergeiBuvaka спасибо, поправил.